# Sending GPS coordinates while screen is off

Tags: android, android-service

I am new to Android but I have an idea and at its core is tracking the device through GPS.
This question is not 100% programming related but here goes:

Can I wakeup a service on an android device through push notification and make the service send the GPS coordinates to my server? Or is it not allowed in Android?

This is needed for my app which is for parents to track their kids when they are out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By off, I assume you mean the screen is off not the phone is turned off.  Yes, you can do it when the screen is off-  you need a background service (probably launched at boot).  The problem is battery-  GPS takes up a LOT of battery.  If you're running constantly, they will not get a full day's charge in their phone.  For a security solution, that's bad-  you don't want to make them unable to dial 911.

You may want to consider using the less accurate but less battery intensive network provider, then switch to GPS only if a closer sync is needed.

Of course, if the kid turns the phone completely off via the power button you can't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

It is technically possible. Use GCM for the push notification. Your app can then respond to that event however it wishes.

However, bear in mind that the device may not be reachable:

- powered down
- airplane mode
- in a spot with craptastic connectivity

Hence, your request to get the location data may or may not succeed.

Also bear in mind that fetching the current location is not necessarily immediate, particularly if you want GPS and the GPS radio is powered down. Handling all of this properly, with `WakeLocks` and whatnot, will be tricky to do without causing major battery drain.